# Angular create operation using MVC angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

How to do Add operation in mvc using angular.

```
var addProductModule = angular.module("addProductModule", []);

addProductModule.factory("addProductService", ['$http', function ($http) {
return
{

    function saveProduct(productToSave)
    {
        $http({

            url : 'AddProduct',
            method : "POST",
            data : productToSave
        })

        return productToSave;
    }
};
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

**Module :**

```
var addProductModule = angular.module("addProductModule", []);
```

**Service**

```
addProductModule.factory("addProductService", ['$http', function ($http) {
    var _saveProduct = function(productToSave)
    {
        var promise = $http({

            url : 'api/Product/AddProduct',
            method : "POST",
            data : productToSave
        })

        return promise;
    }

    return  {
      saveProduct : _saveProduct
    }
 }
}]);
```

**Controller :**

```
addProductModule.controller("addProductController", 
 ["addProductService", function(addProductService) {

  $scope.addProduct = function(product) {
     addProductService.saveProduct(product)
             .then(function success(response) {
          //  do something on success
     }, function error(reason) {
         // do something on error
     });
  }
}]);
```

**WebApi**

```
public class ProductController : ApiController
{
     public ActionResult AddProduct(Product p)
      {
         // add the product
      }
}
```

Comment: This is correct. I would only "suggest" that I wouldn't define the resource in the _saveProduct().

Comment: what do you suggest ? the _saveProduct is with in the addProductService.  Isn't the best approach to use a separate service for such http operations. Tomorrow a new method _getProduct can be added to addProductService (the name ProductService is more meaningful though) and the service can be used acoss the app through DI. Makes a neat separation.

Comment: All I was suggesting was that you declare your resource, then refer to that in the method, in cleans things up a bit if the url changes.  As an example....https://gist.github.com/dougrchamberlain/5b99d726932ffda57dd8